# AttributeError: type object 'Robo4_Board has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: tkinter

My tkinter program has worked well but it takes a long time to load.
I used classes so that I could use modules vs having the whole program in one file/module (not sure of which term).
I copied the CheckWinner script to a new page and imported it to the main program.

Now I get an error about attributes?

The code is on a Raspberry Pi and is hard to extract to my PC.
Robo4_Board is the main class where the screen and most variables are defined.

ERRORS
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/TESTS/ROBO4_TEST_B.py", line 16, in combined_func f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/TESTS/ROBO4_TEST_CheckWinner_A.py", line 17, in CheckWinner_A robo4.br_y_0=tk.Button(ROBO4_TEST_B.robo4,text = "Red Wins", padx=2, pady=2, bg=r, fg="black") File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2369, in **init** Widget.**init**(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2292, in **init** BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2262, in _setup self.tk = master.tk AttributeError: type object 'Robo4_Board' has no attribute 'tk'

What do I have to do to get the links working properly?
Not sure where the code should go.
I have revised the code to represent what works with CheckWinner in the same frame as ROBO4_TEST_B.

## This is ROBO4_TEST_List_A

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
g = "green"
r = "dark red"
y = "yellow"

class Robo4_List():

    robo4_B ={}
    robo4_B = [g,g]
```

## This is ROBO4TEST_B

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from ROBO4_TEST_List_A import Robo4_List
from ROBO4_TEST_CheckWinner_A import *

redwins = 0
yelwins = 0

g = "green"
r = "dark red"
y = "yellow"

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func

class Robo4_Board(tk.Tk):
    bpadx = 65
    bpady = 40
    bpadx1 = 0
    bpadx4 = 6.6
    sy = 2.8
    bpady1 = 14
    bpady2 = bpady1-sy
    global wtx
    global wtx2
    global wty
    wtx = 100
    wtx2 = 900
    wty = 670
    c_color = r
    bgcolor = g
    br_y_color = {}
    br_y_color = [g, g, g]
    windelay = 500
    scoreboard = 1500
    playagain = 2000
    redwin = 0
    yelwin = 0

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, ScoreBoard):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller
        sp_label = tk.Label(self, text="Let's Play ROBO 4")
        sp_label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", pady=10)
br_y_0=tk.Button(self,activebackground="green",repeatdelay=10,padx=robo4.bpadx,             pady=robo4.bpady,bg=robo4.bgcolor,command=combine_funcs(b_all0,CheckWinner.CheckWinner_A))

        br_y_0.place(x=robo4.bpadx*robo4.bpadx1, y=robo4.bpady*robo4.bpady1)

        scoreboard=tk.Button(self,padx=2, pady=2, bg="white",\
                    text=("RED  =  {}   YELLOW  =  {}"\
                     .format(redwins, yelwins)),\
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ScoreBoard"))

        robo4_check=tk.Button(self, padx=2, pady=2, bg="white",\
                    text=("PLAY AGAIN"),command=combine_funcs(lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")))

        robo4_check.place(x=300, y=670)
        scoreboard.place(x=600, y=670)

        controller.geometry("1000x700")

        whos_turn=tk.Button(self,text="Your Turn",padx=2,pady=2,bg=robo4.c_color)
        whos_turn.place(x=wtx,y=wty)
        whos_turn2=tk.Button(self,text="Your Turn",padx=2,pady=2,bg=robo4.c_color)
        whos_turn2.place(x=wtx2,y=wty)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        po_label = tk.Label(self, text="WE HAVE A WINNER")
        po_label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x" , pady=10)
        back_play=tk.Button(self, wraplength= 140, padx=2, pady=2, bg="white",text=("Click to Play Again"),
```

command=combine_funcs(lambda:  controller.show_frame("StartPage")))
            back_play.place(x=300, y=670)

```
class ScoreBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        sb_label = tk.Label(self, text="Score Board")
        sb_label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x" , pady=10)
        checkscore=tk.Button(self, wraplength=100,padx=robo4.bpadx-44, pady=robo4.bpady-8, bg="white",\
                    text=("Check Score?"\
                     .format(redwins, yelwins)),
                    command=combine_funcs(lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")))
        checkscore.place(x=robo4.bpadx*robo4.bpadx4, y=robo4.bpady*robo4.bpady2)

def b_all0():
    if (Robo4_List.robo4_B[0] == "green"):
        Robo4_List.robo4_B[0] = robo4.c_color
robo4.br_y_0=tk.Button(robo4,activebackground=robo4.c_color,padx=robo4.bpadx, pady=robo4.bpady, bg=Robo4_List.robo4_B[0])
        robo4.br_y_0.place(x=robo4.bpadx*robo4.bpadx1, y=robo4.bpady*robo4.bpady1)
    if (robo4.c_color == "dark red"):
        robo4.c_color = "yellow"
    else:
        robo4.c_color = "dark red"
    print (Robo4_List.robo4_B[0:12])
    whos_turn=tk.Button(robo4,text="Your Turn",padx=2,pady=2,bg=robo4.c_color)
    whos_turn.place(x=wtx,y=wty)
    whos_turn2=tk.Button(robo4,text="Your Turn",padx=2,pady=2,bg=robo4.c_color)
    whos_turn2.place(x=wtx2,y=wty)
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from ROBO4_TEST_List_A import Robo4_List
import ROBO4_TEST_A as ROBO4_TEST_A
g = "green"
r = "dark red"
y = "yellow"

class CheckWinner():
    def CheckWinner_A():
        global redwins
        global yelwins
        print(Robo4_List.robo4_B[0])
        if (Robo4_List.robo4_B[0] == r):
            robo4.br_y_0=tk.Button(robo4,text = "Red Wins", padx=2, pady=2, bg=r, fg="black")
            robo4.br_y_0.place(x=200, y=670)
            redwins += 1
            robo4.after(robo4.windelay, robo4.show_frame, "PageOne")
robo4 = Robo4_Board

if __name__ == '__main__':

    robo4 = Robo4_Board()
    robo4.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you add the folders tree in the answer?

Comment: You need to reduce this code down to a [mcve], there is too much code for us to have to sift through. Also, please include the exact error message.

Comment: Reduced as small as I think I can go and still function. By exact error message do you mean all of the lines above the final error?

Comment: this code can't run because you're importing things we don't have.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You are trying to use a *class* rather than a *widget* as the parent of another widget. A parent must always be a widget.

---

Let's look at the error:

```
Robo4_Board' has no attribute 'tk'
```

Tkinter throws an error like this if you pass something other than an actual widget to one of it's classes when it expects a widget. For example, if you do something like `tk.Label("this is a string")` you will get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'`

In your case the error message is this:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Robo4_Board' has no attribute 'tk'
```

That comes from this line:

```
robo4.br_y_0=tk.Button(ROBO4_TEST_B.robo4,...)
```

In this context, `ROBO4_TEST_B.robo4` is a *class* rather than an *instance* of a class. Since a class isn't a widget, tkinter throws the error.

This is possibly due to this line of code:

```
robo4 = Robo4_Board
```

You're defining `robo4` as a *class*, not an *instance* of the class.

*Probably* the solution is to do `robo4 = Robo4_Board()` (note the trailing `()`), but I can't say for certain. I don't know if there are other places in your code where you assume `robo4` is a class rather than an instance. You didn't provide a proper [mcve] so I can't run your code.

Comment: How is it that the checkwinner works when it is in the same frame? I'm looking to place buttons into the initial frame. If I copy the checkwinner into the ROBO4_TEST_B and change ROBO4_TEST_B.robo4 to robo4 everything works with no errors.

Comment: Is there a way to denote the modules? I'll comment where they start.

Comment: Commenting worked great. There are 2 places I could not fix the indenting. I hope this help resolve my issue. Thanks for your time and effort and most of all understanding & patience

Comment: @drazz52: I don't know what you mean by _"how is it that the checkwinner works"_. You don't use `checkwinner` in a place that expects a widget. The bottom line is that you're passing a non-widget value to an argument that requires a widget.

Comment: I have revised the code to represent what works with CheckWinner inside the same frame as ROBO4_TEST_B. Inside of StartPage the button br_y_0 has a command to CheckWinner.CheckWinner_A isn't that calling a widget?

Comment: @drazz52: In the code you posted, `CheckWinner.CheckWinner_A` is a function, not a widget.

Comment: Well I thank you for your time Bryan. I simply wanted to split up a 1943 line program by using classes and modules. When I moved one of the functions to a module of its own I got the original error of no "tk" attribute. Since then I have learned that I am using the wrong feature to complete a working program. Again thanks for your time and if you happen to know how I can split the program up with out errors I'd really appreciate it. I have spent more than a week trying to accomplish this, what seems to me to be a simple task. I know I need a better understanding of Python/Tkinter. Thanks again

Comment: @drazz52: did you even try what I suggested? `robot4 = Robo4_Board()`? My recommendation is to start over. Create the files you want, and absolutely as few lines as possible to make it work. No extra functions, only a single widget in each file, simple function and class names. Get that working before trying to add more code. As it is now, your code is too complex and hard to understand.